# Nuances of Drawing Vertical Lines on a Log Plot

Tags: logarithmic-scale, graphics

I'm trying to draw a vertical line on a `LogPlot` using `Epilog`. There is a slight issue in the vertical positioning of the line. When I indicate the line should begin at 1 it instead begins at ~2.75.

```
LogPlot[Exp[x], {x, 0, 3}, Epilog -> Style[Line[{{2, 1}, {2, 10000}}], Thickness[.005]]]
```

Attempting to extend the line by lowering the starting point was unsuccessful. Raising the line works, but the starting point still doesn't correspond exactly to that requested. The issue is absent when doing a `Plot` command and present when doing other variants of `Plot` where the axis are on a Log scale.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
LogPlot[Exp[x], {x, 0, 3}, 
 Epilog -> Style[Line[{{2, Log@1}, {2, 10000}}], Thickness[.005]]]
```

[image]